# How to serialize GUID properties as string in MongoDb?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I want to serialize a `Dictionary<string, object>` object in such a way that whenever the value is a `Guid` (or within the object graph of the value there is a `Guid`), the `Guid` is serialized as a string.

I tried running the following test:

```
Guid id = new ("11536e02-fcf3-4a8f-8b1d-ddfa6b4cee8a");
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(new GuidSerializer(BsonType.String));
string json1 = BsonExtensionMethods.ToJson(id); // "11536e02-fcf3-4a8f-8b1d-ddfa6b4cee8a"
string json2 = BsonExtensionMethods.ToJson(new[] {id}); // ["11536e02-fcf3-4a8f-8b1d-ddfa6b4cee8a"]
string json3 = BsonExtensionMethods.ToJson(new {Id = id}); // { "Id": "11536e02-fcf3-4a8f-8b1d-ddfa6b4cee8a" }
string json4 = BsonExtensionMethods.ToJson(new Dictionary<string, object> {["Id"] = id}); // { "Id" : CSUUID("11536e02-fcf3-4a8f-8b1d-ddfa6b4cee8a") }
```

Everything works fine up to `json4` which I expected to be identical to `json3`, but for some reason nested GUID values in dictionaries are still serialized in binary. How do I tell MongoDB to globally serialize *all* GUIDs as strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the standard serializer for dictionaries in the MongoDB.Driver (observed in version 2.17.1) uses `ObjectSerializer`, which simply ignores the registered serializers for certain value types. This is arguably a bug. The workaround is to write and register your own serializers for dictionaries, arrays and objects.

Comment: it's not a bug, maybe missed feature, you register serializer for one type (`guid`) but actually work with different (`object`)

Comment: I disagree. `ObjectSerializer` does respect the global Guid serialization settings to *some* degree but not correctly. It also respects the registered custom serializers for *most* reference types but not for a certain hardcoded list of (mainly value) types. This is arguably a bug, or at the very least, an inconsistency.

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary is created as `<string, object>`, so effectively a type you use is `object`, not `Guid`, to fix it, set `Guid` generic type explicitly:

```
string json4 = BsonExtensionMethods.ToJson(new Dictionary<string, Guid> { ["Id"] = id });
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The point is that I don't have a `Dictionary<string, Guid>`, but a `Dictionary<string, object>` which may or may not contain Guids or arrays of Guids or nested Dictionaries with Guids somehwere.

Comment: in this case, driver uses ObjectSerializer which means that your configuration is ignored